# Why video opened in safari has a black border when resizing?

Tags: css, video, safari

I have this weird problem under safari. A mp4 video with size of 1920 * 1080, if I open it directly under safari, and resize safari to 937px width, then I got:

[image]

There's a black border over the video. And here's the computed style of the `video` element:

[image]

The `width` doesn't equal to 327, but 326 - I'm not sure what's going on here.

Then I check the same mp4 video in chrome:

[image]

No border over the video. And here's the computed style for `video` element under chrome:

[image]

I thought `object-fit: cover` might fix it in safari, but it didn't.

What can I do to fix it under safari now? Any suggestion?

### Edit

Here's a gif showing what I got:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You **cannot** change the default behavior of Safari in this instance. Opening the video *directly* will always end up with this result. You have no control over any direct media pages (MP4, MP3, JPEG, GIF, etc).

### Edit

The next best thing you can do is load it into a basic HTML file (using `<iframe>` or `<video>`) and customize the settings there.

You can simply apply a `border` of `0` the video element like so:

```
video {
  border: 0;
}
```

to remove the black line.

Comment: Actually I got the problem under safari when embedding mp4 video in our site, so I could control the `video` element with CSS. The problem here is why `object-fit: cover` doesn't work under safari in this case.

Comment: Could you provide a working example somewhere and post it here?

Comment: If you check the screenshot I posted before, there's no border around the video.

Comment: You can check it here https://blog.zfanw.com/test/. Enter the safari responsive design mode, then resize the window. You will find the black border at some width.